# Jackson XmlMapper XML Serialization of Java Map With Wrapper Entry Element

Tags: java, xml, jackson, deserialization, xml-deserialization

The question is about Jackson XML Map serializing and deserializing. By default Jackson expects keys of the map to be XML elements themselves.

```
<MyMap>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
</MyMap>
```

But this makes it impossible to have keys which are invalid XML element names.

Is there a way in Jackson to deserialize XML with wrapping entry XML element, like below?

```
<MyMap>
    <MyEntry>
        <Key>key1</Key>
        <Value>value1</Value>
    </MyEntry>
    <MyEntry>
        <Key>key2</Key>
        <Value>value2</Value>
    </MyEntry>
</MyMap>
```

I've seen [`@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki/Jackson-XML-annotations) but it doesn't seem to allow naming an entity's XML element, it names the map's XML element instead. I don't know if it's a bug or expected behavior. But I hope there's a way around it.

The demonstration code I am using in case somebody wants to reproduce

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class ReproductionTest {

    private static final String XML = """
<MyRoot>
    <MyMap>
        <MyEntry><Key>key1</Key><Value>value1</Value></MyEntry>
        <MyEntry><Key>key2</Key><Value>value2</Value></MyEntry>
        <!--33Key3>Not an option since I don't control keys to have valid XML names</33Key3-->
    </MyMap>
    <MyString>abc</MyString>
</MyRoot>""";

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    static class MyRoot {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MyMap")
        // With the next line uncommented, the following exception is thrown:
        // UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "MyMap"...
        // not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "MyString", "MyEntry"])
        //@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "MyEntry")
        Map<String, String> myMap;
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MyString")
        String myString;
    }

    @Test
    public void reproducesDeserializationIssue() throws JsonProcessingException {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        MyRoot myRoot = xmlMapper.readValue(XML, MyRoot.class);
        xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true); // re-enforcing default
        assertEquals("abc", myRoot.getMyString());          // passes
        assertEquals(1, myRoot.getMyMap().size());          // passes
        assertNotNull(myRoot.getMyMap().get("MyEntry"));    // passes, unexpectedly
        assertEquals("", myRoot.getMyMap().get("MyEntry")); // passes, unexpectedly
        assertNull(myRoot.getMyMap().get("key1"));          // passes, unexpectedly
        assertNull(myRoot.getMyMap().get("key2"));          // passes, unexpectedly
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(myRoot));
        // Prints <MyRoot><myMap><myItem></myItem></myMap><myString>abc</myString></MyRoot>
    }
}
```

P.S. At this point I don't have control over XML schema, nor output POJOs. But I have control over XmlMapper configuration. So it's my understanding that my options are limited to MixIns and custom deserializers. But hope there's an easier solution.

Comment: I ended up using MixIns with custom map serializers (that deserializers into list before translating into map).

Answer (score 0):

As you observed in your post the problem stands in the fact that the usual standard way of deserializing a map cannot be applied to the xml you provided, but you can interpret the xml as a list of `MyEntry` class and deserialize it as a list. Starting from the initial xml:

```
<MyMap>
    <MyEntry>
        <Key>key1</Key>
        <Value>value1</Value>
    </MyEntry>
    <MyEntry>
        <Key>key2</Key>
        <Value>value2</Value>
    </MyEntry>
</MyMap>
```

You can define two classes named `MyRoot` and `MyEntry` like below:

```
@Data
public class MyRoot {

    //a MyEntry tag is a MyEntry element of the list
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MyEntry")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    List<MyEntry> myMap;
}

@Data
public class MyEntry {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Key")
    private String key;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Value")
    private String value;
}
```

You can note that now the `myMap` is a `List` instance that contains the `MyEntry` objects, now you can deserialize the xml with the expected result:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
MyRoot myRoot = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, MyRoot.class);
//ok, it prints MyRoot(myMap=[MyEntry(key=key1, value=value1), MyEntry(key=key2, value=value2)])
System.out.println(myRoot);
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought about this approach. Unfortunately I don't have control over output POJOs, cannot replace Map to List. Final output type is pretty large, would require having intermediate ~50 classes that work with Lists, and then logic to copy from intermediate to final POJOs. I'm trying to avoid that.